# Compare the cardinalities of $2^{(2^\mathbb N)}$ and $(2^\mathbb N)^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

A set $X^Y$ is defined as the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$. (Sorry for the mistake earlier where I had written $X$ to $Y$ earlier).

$2^X$ is defined as the set of all subsets of $X$ or equally well as the set of all functions from $X$ to $[2]= 1,2$ .

Please provide a strict inequality/equality w.r.t the cardinalities of the above mentioned sets.

P.S. I am not sure which of the tags elementary-set-theory or set-theory is more suitable for this question.

EDIT: A slight clarification. The only thing I know about cardinalities is that there are five relations defined on them, the equality and the four inequalities, with their standard properties of transitivity, reflexivity etc. I do not know of any operations on cardinalities, except for finite sets.

The abovementioned question can be solved if we know that $2^{(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)}$ and $(2^\mathbb N)^{\mathbb N}$ have the same cardinality, as mentioned in one of the answers. I am unable to find a proof for the same.

Comment: Is this homework (or self-study homework)?  Where did you come across this problem?  (A small hint: do you know any identities for whole numbers of the form $\left(a^b\right)^c$?  Can you figure out whether that applies to your second value?)

Comment: Usually, $X^Y$ is defined as the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes. Sorry for that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, no it was a problem for a test. I do not know of a proof where we could show that the cardinality of $2^{(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)}$ and $({2^\mathbb N})^{\mathbb N}$ are equal. In the treatment of cardinalities in our course, we have considered that they are ordered, nothing else. There is no connection with numbers.

Comment: Five relations defined on cardinals???

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I have mentioned the four inequalities and one equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Use a bijection from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ to show that there is a bijection between ${}^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}2$ and ${}^{\Bbb N}2$. (I prefer the notation ${}^XY$ for the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.)

> **Added:** Then construct the natural bijection between ${}^{\Bbb N}\left({}^{\Bbb N}2\right)$ and ${}^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}2$. You can define it in either direction, but I find it a little more natural to start with a function $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to 2$ and convert it to a sequence $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of functions $f_n:\Bbb N\to 2$ by $f_n(m)=f(\langle ?,?\rangle)$?

Finally, use Cantor’s theorem.

Comment: Agreed, that notation is much better. UNLESS we're writing things backwards (as in $f : Y \leftarrow X$) in which case $Y^X$ is better.

Comment: @user18921: Don’t you mean $Y\leftarrow X:f$? :-)

Comment: Never thought of that!

Comment: The part that you have given as a hint has been solved. But won't I be required to show that there is a bijection between $2^{(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)}$ and $({2^\mathbb N})^{\mathbb N}$ to complete the proof? I do not understand how you might do that without defining exponentiation for cardinalities (which we haven't done in our course).

Comment: @varun I'm a little confused; if you haven't defined exponentiation for cardinalities then the question makes almost no sense in the first place.

Comment: @varun: I wasn’t sure which part would cause more trouble and guessed wrong. I’ve added a bit to point you in the right direction for the other part; see if it’s enough.

Answer (score 2):

The remaining portion of the question — a special case of showing that $\left(A^B\right)^C\equiv A^{B\times C}$ for all sets $A, B, C$ — can be handled by the classical notion of *currying*: a function $f:(B\times C)\mapsto A$ can be canonically thought of as a function of two arguments, $f(b,c)$ where the first argument is $b\in B$ and the second argument is $c\in C$, whereas a function $g: C\mapsto (B\mapsto A)$ is a function that takes a value $c\in C$ and returns a *function* $h:B\mapsto A$ which takes a value $b\in B$ and returns a value in $A$.  But given such a function $g$ we can *define* $f:(B\times C)\mapsto A$ as $f(b,c)=\left(g(c)\right)(b)$, and contrariwise, given such an $f$ we can define a function $g$ as $g(c) = f(\_,c)$.  Note that this proof also works in the case where $A,B,C$ are all *finite* sets, and gives a combinatorial proof of the classical identity $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$.